# how do I check an http request response status code from iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsurlconnection, http-status-codes

I am sending an http request from iOS (iPad/iPhone) to my python google app engine server using the `NSURLConnection` and `NSURLRequest` classes.

How do I read the response's status, i.e. the value set by app engine using `response.set_status(200, message="Success")` for instance?

I'm not able to find where I can read these status codes once I receive the `NSURLConnection's` `connectionDidFinishLoading` delegate call on the client end.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieve HTTPResponse/HTTPRequest status codes iPhone SDK?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/917932/retrieve-httpresponse-httprequest-status-codes-iphone-sdk)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `connection:didReceiveResponse:` delegate method is called when a response is received, which gives you an `NSURLResponse` to play with.

If you've made an HTTP request, then it'll actually be an `NSHTTPURLResponse` object, which has a `statusCode` method.

Answer (score 16):

If you are sending a synchronous request, you could get the response code from NSHTTPURLResponse.

```
NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error = nil;

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL_LOGIN]];
NSData *respData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSLog(@"~~~~~ Status code: %d", [response statusCode]);
```

Hope this will help you :)