# Ping with iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I need to do a network ping in an iPhone app, but `NSHost` is an unsupported framework for iPhone OS. Does anybody know of other tools or techniques to achive similar functionality?

Comment: Some answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/798454/how-to-write-a-simple-ping-method-in-cocoa-objective-c

Answer (score 0):

Search for Reachability. Have a loot at e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477852/checking-for-internet-connectivity-in-objective-c) SO question. With this, you can test if a host can be reached.

HTH

Comment: In this context the definition of reachable is that a packet can be sent out to a specific host. Reachability does not check if that packet ever makes it to the server. A ping would however send out the packet to the server, and wait for the server to return a packet. Reachability and Ping are therefore not interchangeable.