# iOS/iPhone How to ping a server ip address?

Tags: iphone, ios, ping, bonjour

everyone

I create a Bonjour browser to find local server,I can collect many host name,and parser the IP.

But when the network is not stable , I can't find any server in local network...

But if you use ping to find server , it never failed to get server IP

Is there a way to ping external server without using Bonjour or give a host name ???

If I can't get the host name now , how to get all the server IP in local network ???

Thanks for all reply or answers.

Here is the search result I found

[Checking For Internet Connectivity in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477852/checking-for-internet-connectivity-in-objective-c)

[Ping with iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130963/ping-with-iphone-sdk)

Webber

Comment: I think the last part of Bonjour is like to ping a host name's IP,so it should just pass browser search the server and get the host name directly to parser server information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want ping your local host server with IP address I recommend:
[SimplePingerHelper](https://github.com/chrishulbert/SimplePingHelper)
.

For more information about this class go to: http://www.splinter.com.au/how-to-ping-a-server-in-objective-c-iphone/

Add method to perform every second and delegate to check success or failure.