# How to ping a server from iOS application?

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.3, ios5.1

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ping with iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130963/ping-with-iphone-sdk)

I am creating a application. Where before sending request to server i need to long server. How can i do that?

Comment: Didn't you asking this same question already?

Comment: more relevant answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8132827/how-to-ping-or-check-if-server-of-particular-ip-address-is-available-connected-i

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check the reachability utility that Apple made:

[Reachability on developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html)

I think that will do what you want to do.

**EDIT**

use it like this:

```
+(BOOL)canConnect {
    Reachability *r = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.example.com"];
    NetworkStatus internetStatus = [r currentReachabilityStatus];
    return ((internetStatus == ReachableViaWiFi) || (internetStatus == ReachableViaWWAN));
}
```

It will check if you can connect to the internet, and if you can connect to the server with the given adress/ip.

Comment: I tried that one also . But i was just able to check weather my device is connected to network or not.   But my requirement  is that i need to ping server.

Comment: I tried this when I was connected to a WIFI with no internet access. But currentReachabilityStatus is always ReachableViaWifi. Even if the reachability instance is created like [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"Dummy"]

Comment: Incorrect answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Reachability example in apple.  That provides step by step to check if ip is connectable.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a lot of variants starting from `NSURLRequest` and so on