# Show error message is internet not available

Tags: objective-c

I'm loading a `webview` and am using `SVProgressHUD` to display a loading message whilst the page is loaded.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _infowebView.delegate = self;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com"];
    [self.infowebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Loading"];
}
```

> Is it possible to show an error message if there isn't an internet connection available, if so how would i do this?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477852/checking-for-internet-connectivity-in-objective-c

Comment: you can check internet connectivity before you initiate internet required code, use [readability classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html).

Comment: I simply used this:- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [SVProgressHUD showInfoWithStatus:@"Internet Connection Unavailable"];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
} Is this bad practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before loading the page you can check the internet connection using the reachability class:

```
+(BOOL)IsInternet
{
    Reachability *networkReachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    NetworkStatus networkStatus = [networkReachability currentReachabilityStatus];
    if (networkStatus == NotReachable)
    {
        return NO;
    }
    else
    {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

**How to use:**

```
if([className IsInternet]){
//Load the page
}else{
// Show message internet not available
}
```